# Passing variable ClientID to JavaScript function to show/hide DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I have an ASPX page with 3 HTML Buttons that all fire the same JS function along with a single parameter. The buttons pass the id of a DIV and the function shows/hides that DIV.

I can get this to work if it is one function for each button (with hard coded value) but I can't seem to figure out how to make it so the function accepts the ClientID as a parameter.

```
<button id="a_button" onclick="Show_Hide_Display('<%=section_a.ClientID%>');return false">Section A</button>
<button id="b_button" onclick="Show_Hide_Display('<%=section_b.ClientID%>');return false">Section B</button>
<button id="c_button" onclick="Show_Hide_Display('<%=section_c.ClientID%>');return false">Section C</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Show_Hide_Display(divID) {

        var div = document.getElementById(divID);

        if (div.style.display == "" || div.style.display == "block") {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }

        return false;
    }

</script>
```

I have tried severl things including the above, which results in:

```
TypeError: Div is null
```

EDIT:

This is where the DIVs that will be shown/hidden are built (in a DIV below the DIV containing the buttons, above the JavaScript).

```
<div id="pdp_section_a_intro" class="pdp_section_a_intro" runat="server">
    <h2>Section A</h2>
    <div id="section_a" Class="pdp_section" runat="server" style="display:none;">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pdp_subssections_a_ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pdp_section_b_intro" class="pdp_section_b_intro" runat="server">
    <h2>Section B</h2>
    <div id="section_b" Class="pdp_section" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pdp_subssections_b_ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pdp_section_c_intro" class="pdp_section_c_intro" runat="server">
    <h2>Section C</h2>
    <div id="section_c" Class="pdp_section" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pdp_subssections_c_ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than passing client id in function "Show_Hide_Display", pass flag like 1 or 2 or 3 for div. and in the function check condition if 1 then document.getElementById('<%=section_a.ClientID%>') and so fourth. It will definitely works

Comment: I guess this could work, as long as you knew how many DIVs there were going to be.  The next step of this project is to have dynamically generated DIVs and Buttons so the function needs to be able to hanle these without knowing before hand the DIVs it is going to affect.

Comment: Yes you are right as I saw your HTML, I thought it would be static. That is why I gave you this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use any server side control, you cannot embed server side code inside. Can you please try below,

In ASPX page,

```
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="Button 3" />
```

In Code Behind,

```
    btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Show_Hide_Display('" & section_a.ClientID & "');return false;")
    btn2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Show_Hide_Display('" & section_b.ClientID & "');return false;")
    btn3.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Show_Hide_Display('" & section_c.ClientID & "');return false;")
```

Comment: I just tried this and it results in the same error: 'TypeError: Div is null'

Comment: Can you please comment everything within javascript function and just try to display divID in alert. alert(divID); Lets see if this function gets correct divID.

Comment: The alert shows the correct Id: 'dnn_ctr435_section_a'

Comment: Now can you check whether getElementById returns correct element? alert(document.getElementById(divID));

Comment: So it means that, it didn't find correct div within page source. Can you show me where/how you created those div?

Comment: Added the area concerning the shown/hidden DIVs as an edit to question

Comment: I think, it is correct. Now can you check one more thing, there is visible = false for those divs in code behind. If there is visible=false set for those divs, you cannot get them in javascript.

Comment: I have cleaned the code behind right back to the basics (including taking the code out of asp:Placeholders).  At the moment, when the buttons are clicked I get the following (different) error: 'TypeError: divID.style is undefined'

Comment: Instead of divID.style use divID.attributes.add("style","display: none")

Comment: Error has changed to: error: 'TypeError: divID.attributes is undefined'.  I think the id is still not being passed properly or the function cannot find the element represented by the id.

Comment: Is it possible, if you can show me? So that I can exactly identify problem.

Comment: OK I think this is fixed now.  I had left the code inside an asp:Placeholder that had 'visible=false' (missed it when clearing out the code).  I removed this so the code was very basic and it works fine now with any DIV id i pass into the function.  Thank you for your help.